# Mvc ModelBinder Serializer/Deserializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Anyone knows what kind of serializer is being used by Asp.NET Mvc?

I'm sure you have noticed when you try to print the following class to the view.

```
public class Class
{
     Pupil[] Pupils {get;set;}
     Instructor Instructor {get;set;}
}
```

You get something like this on postback:

```
Pupils[0]=Me&Pupils[1]=Abc&Instructor=Some1 //Ala Mvc Modelbinder when you post the model back to server.
```

Or if you call the controller action from jQuery AJAX, the JSON object gets serialized to the following query in the URI:

```
Class[Pupil][0]=Me&Class[Pupil][1]=Abc&Class[Instructor]="Some1" //Ala. JQuery Get Serializer
```

What is the name of the above two serializers? Where is this library in C#?

I want to pass complex type via URI (http GET) into my WebAPI by taking advantage of the fact the model binder is able to bind the above into the correct complex type. The Web API might be called both from client (via. JavaScript) and also from server side (in C#).

Comment: URL accepts only primitive type such as int, strings, decimals... because it still is a text. 

It should like this: 

`Instructor.PropertyA=value&&Instructor.PropertyB=value&Pupils[0].PropertyX=Value&Pupils[0].Propertyy=Value&Pupils[1].PropertyX=Value&Pupils[1].PropertyY=Value`

Comment: Yes, but is there anything that will serialize an C# class into the above string.